# Slow serialization of ndarray to TFRecord

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, serialization, protocol-buffers

I'd like to serialize large numpy `ndarray` to `TFRecord`. Trouble is, the process if painfully slow. For an array size of (1000000, 65) it takes almost a minute. Serializing the same to other binary format (HDF5, npy, parquet...) takes less than a second. I am pretty sure there's a much faster way to serialize it, but I just can't figure it out.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

X = np.random.randn(1000000, 65)

def write_tf_dataset(data: np.ndarray, path: str):
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(path=path) as writer:
        for record in data:
            feature = {'X': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=record[:42])),
                       'Y': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=record[42:64])),
                       'Z': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[record[64]]))}
            example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
            serialized = example.SerializeToString()
            writer.write(serialized)

write_tf_dataset(X, 'X.tfrecord')
```

How to increase performance of `write_tf_dataset`? Size of my `X` is 200x larger than in the snippet.

I am not the first one to complain about the slow performance of `TFRecord`. Based on [this Tensorflow Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30372) I made a second version of the function:

```
import pickle

def write_tf_dataset(data: np.ndarray, path: str):
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(path=path) as writer:
        for record in data:
            feature = {
                'X': tf.io.serialize_tensor(record[:42]).numpy(),
                'Y': tf.io.serialize_tensor(record[42:64]).numpy(),
                'Z': tf.io.serialize_tensor(record[64]).numpy(),
            }
            serialized = pickle.dumps(feature)
            writer.write(serialized)
```

... but if performed even worse. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is using the `multiprocessing` package. You can write from many processes to the same TFRecord file, or make each process write to a different file (I think having multiple (small) TFRecords is the recommended approach, instead of a single (big) file, since it is faster to read from multiple sources):

```py
import multiprocessing
import os

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def serialize_example(record):
    feature = {
        "X": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=record[:42])),
        "Y": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=record[42:64])),
        "Z": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[record[64]])),
    }
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    return example.SerializeToString()


def write_tfrecord(tfrecord_path, records):
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_path) as writer:
        for item in records:
            serialized = serialize_example(item)
            writer.write(serialized)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    np.random.seed(1234)
    data = np.random.randn(1000000, 65)

    # Option 1: write to a single file
    tfrecord_path = "/home/appuser/data/data.tfrecord"
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_path) as writer:
        for example in p.map(serialize_example, data):
            writer.write(example)

    # Option 2: write to multiple files
    procs = []
    n_shard = 4
    num_per_shard = int(np.ceil(len(data) / n_shard))
    for shard_id in range(n_shard):
        filename = f"data_{shard_id + 1:04d}_of_{n_shard:04d}.tfrecord"
        tfrecord_path = os.path.join("/home/appuser/data", filename)

        start_index = shard_id * num_per_shard
        end_index = min((shard_id + 1) * num_per_shard, len(data))

        args = (tfrecord_path, data[start_index:end_index])
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=write_tfrecord, args=args)
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I eventually did and it turned out that loading data from multiple files takes significantly longer. I have a decent CPU and NVMe drive, so it's not poor hardware that could not handle the IO. What I observed is that using parallel loading, even if number of jobs is 1 (`num_parallel_reads=1`), comes with a significant penalty. In other words, this speeds up the saving, but I get to pay the price later on training (which is worse). Any advice on that?

Comment: I do not know what could be causing it. Maybe you can try to debug the input pipeline with the [`profiler`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler) and look at the trace viewer for some indication of the bottleneck.